# Increase Font Size in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to increase font size in Bootstrap? A functionality to allow the user to increase the font of the whole website.

Is this possible? If there is a way to manually increase the font-size will be helpful too instead of the automated way.

Comment: There is not a single place where u can change to do this. You will have to modify styles using javascript for all areas affected.

Comment: Doesn't zooming the entire page a solution for you? Knowing that zoom won't only affect the font size. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/7pj7u43p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just redefine body styles with large font-size

```
body { font-size: 16px; }
```

or you can customize bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#typography
Just change @font-size-base to the font-size you like.

Answer (score 0):

The default `font-size` is **14px**.

You can use `lead` class which `font-size` is **21px**

Check [reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#lead-body-copy) for more info.

or

add `style="font-size:25px;` attribute to `<body> tag` and change the size according to your need.

Answer (score -2):

Not pretty but this can work.  I haven't tried it.  Create a number of csss, example 120p.css, 140p.css etc.  In 120p.css put

```
body {font-size:120% !important}
```

In 140p.css put

```
body {font-size:140% !important}
```

Finally save the users preference and based on that include the appropriate css.

Comment: i do not think important is a good way to go, as you won't be able to redefine font-size on the child elements without important as well

Comment: Of course not, I said it wasnt pretty.  But if there wasn't any other solution forthcoming, then its a solution.